# Expose imported modules when importing a custom module

Tags: python, import, namespaces

If I create a custom module, Foo, that imports a separate module Bar, I would like for the file that imports Foo to also be able to reference Bar directly as if it were imported into its local namespace. This way, the file could access Foo and Bar as opposed to having to reference Bar as a member of Foo, e.g., Foo.Bar.

I tried adding the following to the __init__.py function in Foo but it didn't work:

```
globals()['Bar'] = Bar
```

Comment: This is not possible in Python.  The imported module does not have access to the namespace that imports it.  You have to explicitly import `Bar` in the module where you want to use it.

Comment: No, no, no! Just import `Bar` when you need anything defined in `Bar`. Explicit is better than implicit.